# Google sign in firebase doesn’t work in release mode flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, digital-signature

I was told to add three keys to log in via Google to the release version, and so I added three sha keys to firebase: I took two sha1 keys in release, debug mode from the project itself, and one key from google console - app signing, got them in google services json and inserted them into the project, and in general, everything works fine in the debug version, but doesn’t in the release mode, google throws an 12500 entry error. I have my support email in firebase console

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the project settings of your firebase app on firebase console
  https://console.firebase.google.com/.
- Open settings tab
- In public settings, provide a valid support email and restart your
  application.

Error `12500` is usually associated with support email, and error `10` is associated with SHA fingerprint.